# Timeout in connect() function from Winsock

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, winapi, winsock

Is there any way to decrease the timeout when I call connect() function from Winsock?
I think it's almost 30 seconds, I want to put 5 seconds.

Comment: It's not clear which of two very different things you want to do. Do you want to change how long before the `connect` call returns? Or do you want to change how long the actual connection operation is willing to wait? The best solution is probably just to not wait more than 5 seconds for `connect` regardless of how long it takes.

Comment: Yes, I want to change how long before the connect call returns. If in 5 seconds it does not work, I give up and go ahead.

Comment: There is no way to change how long `connect()` itself waits before exiting. It is an all-or-nothing kind of function. But you can put the socket in asynchronos/non-blocking mode so that `connect()` will exit immediately, and then you can use `select()`, `WSAEventSelect()`, or `WSAAsyncSelect()` to handle the waiting using whatever timeout you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the socket in non-blocking mode while connecting, and use `select()` with a timeout of 5 seconds to check if the socket is writable. After `select()` exits, the connection is either established or not.  If not, consider the connection timed out and perform error handling as needed.

Comment: But in this way, a connection must be established, right?

Comment: @cna, what do you mean 'must'? After at most 5 seconds you will get control back, and you will know if it was established or not.

Comment: @cna: A non-blocking socket establishes the connection in the background while your code moves on to do other things.  So, set the socket to non-blocking mode (`ioctlsocket(FIONBIO)` set to 1), then call `connect()`. If `connect()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAGetLastError()` returns `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, the connection is in progress, so call `select()` with a 5 second timeout. If `select()` returns success indicating the socket is writable, the connection has been established. Otherwise, close the socket.

Comment: Thanks, and is there any specific kind of socket that I have to create? Could it be `SOCKET socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0);`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you. But all the times I try, the `select()` returns timeout, even if the otherside of the socket is available. I' m doing this way: `timeval timeOut = {0};
  timeOut.tv_sec = 10;
  timeOut.tv_usec = 0;

  fd_set fdset = {0};
  fdset.fd_count = 1;
  fdset.fd_array[0] = socket;

  iRet = select(1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &timeOut);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau got it using writable fd_set. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cna, sorry for not replying - didn't have time on weekend. However, I take it, all is good now?

Comment: @can: Yes, when calling `select()` to wait for `connect()`, you need to test for *writability*, not *readability*. You should also be using the `FD_XXX()` macros instead of manipulating the `fd_set` fields directly, eg: `timeval timeOut = {0}; timeOut.tv_sec = 10; timeOut.tv_usec = 0; fd_set fdset; FD_ZERO(&fdset); FD_SET(socket, &fdset); iRet = select(0, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &timeOut);` Please read the [`select()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, thank you very much! The monitoring is working quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call the ConnectEx() function and pass it the OVERLAPPED.hEvent structure with a pre-created event, for which you can wait with WaitForSingleObject() as short as you want.

ConnectEx() is available only in WindowsXP and above...

```
//The HANDLE Socket MUST BE pre-bound with Bind() before calling this function
int ConnectWithTimout(HANDLE Socket, UINT remIP, WORD remPort, UINT milliseconds)
{
    int iRes, Result;
    UINT OptVal, Flags;
    OVERLAPPED Overlapped;
    sockaddr_in socket_info;


    Result= ERROR_UNEXP_NET_ERR;

    ZeroMemory(&socket_info, sizeof(socket_info));
    ZeroMemory(&Overlapped, sizeof(Overlapped));

    socket_info.sin_addr.S_addr = htonl(remIP);
    socket_info.sin_port = htons(remPort);
    socket_info.sin_family = AF_INET;

    Overlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent(); 
    if ( ConnectEx(Socket, &socket_info, sizeof(socket_info), NULL, 0, NULL, &Overlapped) )
        printf("WOW! Connection succeeded immediately\n");
    else
    {
        iRes = WSAGetLastError();
        if (iRes == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            iRes = WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, milliseconds);  //Wait for x milliseconds to connect
            if (iRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                if (!WSAGetOverlappedResult(socket, &Overlapped, &OptVal, FALSE, Flags))
                {
                    iRes = WSAGetLastError();
                    if (iRes == WSAEADDRINUSE)
                        DoError("WSAGetOverlappedResult() reported that the requested local address is already in use or in a TIME_WAIT state")
                    else
                        DoError("WSAGetOverlappedResult() failed with error: ", iRes);
                }
                else
                {
                    OptVal = 1;
                    iRes = setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT, PCHAR(&OptVal), sizeof(OptVal));
                    if (iRes == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        DoError("setsockopt(SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT) failed with error: ", WSAGetLastError() );

                    printf("Connected to %s : %s\n", inet_ntoa(socket_info.sin_addr), itoa(ntohs(socket_info.sin_port)));
                    Result=NO_ERROR;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (iRes == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
                {
                    DoWarning("ConnectEx() TIMED OUT - ", iRes);
                    Result= ERROR_TIMEOUT;
                }
                else
                    DoError("ConnectEx() failed with error: ", iRes)
            }
        }
        else if (iRes ==  WSAECONNREFUSED)  //After this error, it is OK to try to connect again on this docket.
            DoWarning("ConnectEx() failed with CONNECTION REFUSED: ", 0 )
        else if (iRes =  WSAENETUNREACH)    //After this error, it is OK to try to connect again on this docket.
            DoWarning("ConnectEx() failed with NETWORK UNREACHABLE: ", 0 )
        else if (iRes =  WSAETIMEDOUT)  //After this error, it is OK to try to connect again on this docket.
        {
            DoWarning("ConnectEx() TIMED OUT Immediately:", 0 );
            Result= ERROR_TIMEOUT;
        }
        else
            DoError("ConnectEx() failed with unexpected error: ", iRes )
    }


    WSACloseEvent(Overlapped.hEvent);

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution, but it requires a bit more work, plus ConnectEx would return 10049s.  I ended up using `WSAConnectByName`

Comment: Also see here for a more complete example:
https://gist.github.com/joeyadams/4158972